# Python: How do I print a float with a configurable number of decimals

Tags: python, printing, floating-point, formatting

I want to print some numbers and easily configure how many decimals are displayed. How do I turn something like this:

```
import numpy as np
x, y, z, s = np.random.random(4)
str_out = '[%0.4f,\t%0.4f,\t%0.4f,\t%0.4f]' % (x, y, z, s)
print(str_out)
```

and effectively replace `%0.4f` with a variable

I know I could achieve the same thing by truncating the values before printing them but hoping there is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preprocess the `%`-style format string using `str.format` or f-strings:

```
import numpy as np

x, y, z, s = np.random.random(4)
precision = 6
# Option 1: using str.format
# strf = "[%0.{}f,\t%0.{}f,\t%0.{}f,\t%0.{}f]".format(*([precision] * 4))
# Option 2: using f-string
strf = f"[%0.{precision}f,\t%0.{precision}f,\t%0.{precision}f,\t%0.{precision}f]"
str_out = strf % (x, y, z, s)
print(str_out)  # [0.151736,      0.382490,       0.216538,       0.357179]
```

Comment: `f-string` instead of format? It's newer and encouraged to be used

Comment: @Gameplay Thanks for the suggestion. Using f-strings makes the code more readable, but there are two downsides (that I can think of). First is that it makes the code longer because you have to repeat the variable name every time it is used. Second, it cannot handle variable number of replacements.

Comment: @Fractalism What do you mean by "you have to repeat the variable name every time it is used". Isn't that exactly what you're doing in your example? Regardless... Your answer is considered to be definitive so....

Comment: @Pingu I added the f-string version after @Gameplay's comment. My answer originally used `str.format` (the commented out code), which creates a variable number of arguments to pass into the format string. I commented that out because it seems using f-strings is more suitable for OP's use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in f-string format specifications.

For example:

```
from random import random

for dp in range(2, 10):
    v = random()
    print(f'{v:.{dp}f}')
```

**Example output:**

```
0.62
0.781
0.2481
0.83453
0.170137
0.2646456
0.03279264
0.637595719
```

Answer (score 1):

with
[numpy.set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)  you can print things elegantly

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
print(np.random.random(4))
```